# Kubernetes "rollout history" command fails with "namespace not found" for service account

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I try to run this command with a service account from Jenkins:
`kubectl rollout history deployment.v1.apps/config-service-deployment`
The command fails with the following error:

```
Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "build" not found
```

I would like to mention, we have only one namespace: **default**;

This is the service account:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-09-09T05:50:56Z"
  name: jenkins-user
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "387323"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/serviceaccounts/jenkins-user
  uid: ********
secrets:
- name: ********
```

If I login from bash and use the default account the command runs successfully and the history is returned.
The service account is working for creating new deployments and services. The only issue is, I can't get the rollout history.

What do I miss?

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl config view`, with especial focus on the default namespace in the kubeconfig for your `rollout` command (it may be in an environment variable `$KUBECONFIG`, or in `$HOME/.kube/config`); either way, you can theoretically side-step all doubt by being explicit about the NS in which the deployment is happening: `kubectl -n default rollout history deploy/config-service-deployment`

Comment: @mdaniel the namespace parameter did the trick! Thank you for this, I don't know how I forgot about it. Can you add it as a response, so I can approve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can side-step all doubt about what namespace is in the global `$KUBECONFIG` by being explicit about the namespace in which the deployment is happening:

`kubectl -n default rollout history deploy/config-service-deployment`